# Globe GL - How To Combine Labels Layer With Earthquake Data?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl-globe

I'm trying to combine Globe GL's Labels Layer with USGS data but I'm facing some challenges. The issue arises when adding Label Layer code into the existing setup I have. It all works and a globe is displayed until '// Points' comment is inserted.

1. Is the Label Layer code wrong? I tried to follow the [earthquake globe](https://globe.gl/example/earthquakes/) example for the naming.
2. Did I insert the Layer code wrongly? It does not work even if I combined the function containing label properties with the above function with document.getElementbyId.

```js
            const world = Globe({ animateIn: false })(
              document.getElementById("globeViz")
            )
              .globeImageUrl(
                "//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-blue-marble.jpg"
              )
              .bumpImageUrl(
                "//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-topology.png"
              );

            world.backgroundColor("hsl(245 10% 10%)");
            world.width(710);
            world.height(650);

            // Auto-rotate
            world.controls().autoRotate = true;
            world.controls().autoRotateSpeed = 0.63;

            // Points
            fetch(
              "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.geojson"
            )
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((equakes) => {
                world.labelsData(equakes.features);
              });

            const world = Globe()
              .labelsData(equakes.features)
              .labelLabel((d) => d.properties.title)
              .labelLat((d) => d.geometry.coordinates[1])
              .labelLng((d) => d.geometry.coordinates[0])
              .labelText((d) => d.properties.title)
              .labelSize((d) => Math.sqrt(d.properties.mag) * 4e-4)
              .labelDotRadius((d) => Math.sqrt(d.properties.mag) * 4e-4)
              .labelColor(() => "rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.75)")
              .labelResolution(2)(document.getElementById("globeViz"));
```